# JSF rendered condition

Tags: jsf

I have the following GUI elements: a dropdown menu to select whether you want to input text by yourself or you want to select from predefined texts.

```
<h:form id="test">
<div>
  <h:outputLabel value="Please select:" />
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.selection}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Input text" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Select from predefined texts" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
<div>
  <h:outputLabel value="Your text: " />
  <h:inputText value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 1}" />
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 2}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="Preselected text 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="22" itemLabel="Preselected text 2" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
</h:form>
```

How do I program the rendered conditions right?

UPDATE: When the form loads, 1 is already selected, so the inputText is rendered. The problem is that nothing happens when I change the selection to 2. We use a modified JSF library based on JSF 1.2

Comment: `rendered` conditions are correct, but you'd need to use `a4j` to make the components appear/dissapear when the user selects a value from the first `selectOneMenu`. Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: I guess I can also use javascript. Is there an onclick for the h:selectOneMenu?

Comment: JavaScript is executed on client... I'd say it's not possible to change JSF attributes using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using Richfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like to use `a4j` library you can just `show/hide` the components by using `javascript` as below.
Add `onchange` event to your first `selectOneMenu`

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.selection}" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
```

Add `Id`s to your `textBox` and `selectOneMenu` as below.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 1}" id="myText"/>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 2}" id="mySelectMenu">
```

Finally your `javascript` function should be as below.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(selection) {
        if(selection == 1) {
            document.getElementById("test:myText").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("test:mySelectMenu").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test:myText").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("test:mySelectMenu").style.display = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You'd like to replace `rendered="false"` by `style="display:none"`, otherwise there's no HTML representation in the client side at all.

Comment: yes, that helps. my biggest problem was actually getting the contents of the selection dropdown - I didn't know about this.value ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any restrictions, I'd suggest using `a4j` to add AJAX capabilities. As you are using JSF 1.2, you'll need to use [RichFaces 3.3.X](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/) libraries and add this tag in your JSF file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
```

And then modify your code using `a4j:support` this way:

```
<h:form id="test">
<div>
  <h:outputLabel value="Please select:" />
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.selection}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Input text" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Select from predefined texts" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="textSection" ajaxSingle="true"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
<div>
  <h:outputLabel value="Your text: " />
  <a4j:outputPanel id="textSection">
      <h:inputText value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 1}" />
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myform.inputText}" rendered="#{myform.selection == 2}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="Preselected text 1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="22" itemLabel="Preselected text 2" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
</h:form>
```

When the user changes the selection from selecOneMenu, the `a4j:outputPanel` that now wraps the components you want to show/hide will be reRendered and the `rendered` attribute will be recalculated.